# I want to change my ubuntu background, not gray color

Tags: gnome, desktop-background

This is my wallpaper.

[image]

When I click the show app button, it looks like this:

[image]

I don't want to let my background color remain gray. I want to select my Wallpaper for this background. I use Ubuntu 22.04 and GNOME 42.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the grey color to a blurred version or normal version of your background. See [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1477645/gnome-customize-application-search-to-see-background-wallpaper).

But you can’t change to another customized background.