# Gnome: Customize application search to see background wallpaper

Tags: 22.04, gnome-shell, search

On `ubuntu 20`, when I was doing a application seach (shortcut: `super` key), I could see my wallpaper in the background

On `ubuntu 22`, I don't see it anymore.

How can I customize `gnome` to see my wallpaper during search ?

Comment: You probably were using an extension to have this effect. By default, while searching an application (i.e., as soon as you start to type), the background is black, and it has always been like that.

Comment: See also [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1477512/i-want-to-change-my-ubuntu-background-not-gray-color/1477560)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Using [Overview Background extension](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/5856/overview-background/), you see the background but it’s blurred.
- You also have [Static background in overview extension](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/4696/static-background-in-overview/) to see the background in a normal version.

First, you should install the "Extension Manager" from the Ubuntu Software Center or install it with this command:

```
sudo apt install gnome-shell-extension-manager
```

Then launch the Extension Manager with [SUPER](https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/ubuntu-help/keyboard-key-super.html) key and type "Extension Manager".

Finally, search for either "Overview Background" or "Static background in overview" extension and install it.